# Flutter desktop - change window title from Dart code

Tags: flutter, dart, desktop-application

I am unable to find any way to do that when searching official documentation. Does anybody know any way to do that?

Answer (score 20):

It is possible, as mentioned in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30712

In `pubspec.yaml` add

```
dependencies:
  window_size:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
      path: plugins/window_size
      ref: fd519be1e8398c6b6c2062c2447bac960a71bc02
```

Now in your code just call

```
import 'package:window_size/window_size.dart';

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
setWindowTitle("Custom window title");
```

Works fine on Linux. Haven't tested on Windows/Mac

PS
Thanks to @Johan Ordenes Galleguillos for the missing `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`

Comment: Can't edit answer, but make sure to add WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); before setWindowsTitle("").

Comment: It also worked on Mac.

Comment: I had to use the url `https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git` to get this to work, which is what the referenced issue above used.  The url in this answer on the other hand gave me `pub get failed (server unavailable)` and infinite retries.

Comment: When I run this, the debugger pauses at `setWindowTitle(...)`. I inserted the lines inside the `MainPage.build(...)` function when I run as Chrome executable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Go to windows > runner > main.cpp folder, find a
" !window.CreateAndShow(L"schedule_task", origin, size) "
And change the "schedule_task" text

Comment: While this does work, it removes the ability to use localization functions to have different text for different locales.  If you need that functionality, it's probably better to use the solution from @tomrozb

Comment: Thai text was displayed incorrectly. :(

Answer (score 3):

Achieved this by using [windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) package. It has a lot of features for desktop development with flutter.

After installing package just add this to main():

```
void main() async {
 //needed to ensure binding was initialized 
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await WindowManager.instance.ensureInitialized();
  windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async {
     await windowManager.setTitle('Yor title goes here');
  });

runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

for me worked with Windows and Linux.

references:

[WidgetsFlutterBinding class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding-class.html)

[window manager Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/window_manager/latest/)

Comment: actually you don't need `windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) {}` scope for this, but if you plan, for example, resize your window its's better to have it.

Comment: That works but it also moves the window. Any idea why that is or how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that seems to be not possible (yet), but work in progress: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30712

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace flutter app title on the Windows caption bar, as well as optionally adjusting the dimensions for size and the window coordinates you have to navigate to windows/main.cpp file and edit following code:
!window.Create(L"My App New Title Here", origin, size)
Source:
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/windows/building

Comment: That way you can set default size and title, you can't change title dynamically while app is running

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35720374)